# Serialized incoming aidl calls in one Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, ipc, aidl

I have an App (Client) that performs remote calls using AIDL to a second App (Server). Each call to through the Binder is executed in the Server app in a different thread (TID) as designed by AIDL solution.

Is it possible to make all calls executed in the Server app be executed in just one thread? We have control over all callers (Client apps) and they will perform call in a serial mode and we don't need Server app perform the calls in a multithread way.

So, if the Client App 1 performs a remote call to a method that takes 30 seconds and before it, a second Client App 2 performs a call to the same method (or even other method) we want this second call be executed in the same Thread of the first call.

Messenger is not an option for now.

=== Updated ====

Message is not an option (for now). Here more details: We have a service with 2 type of binders: a) TransacionManager (tm) and DAOImpl (dao).

We first do a call to tm.begin() in the client and even its processed synchronously, on the Service side its is executed in a thread from Thread Pool (android aidl code). This thread TID #1 performs the  begin transaction command in SQLite database.

Then we do a call to dao.selectNextId() - synchronously - and in the Service it is executed in the TID #2. In the selectNextId() method we check if the database is inTransaction and it returns false.

To confirm that the threads was the problem, we put everything in a single call to another binder (allDAO). So when we call allDAO.do() it runs on the Service side in another thread TID #3 and performs begin transc and insert very well.

Not sure if the problem is SQLite that manage different threads as separated requests (how to deal with)...  We just want the Service (using aidl) perform every call from any clients in a same single thread everytime.

Comment: so use a `Handler` on a `Service` side to send a `Message` to a specific thread but honestly it doesn't pay off...

Comment: @pskink Please read my update. Best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Mario on this issue and using the @pskink's [code](http://pastebin.com/PDBCxzZ5) snippet we solved the multithreading issue.

The issue was solved redirecting all aidl calls to the main thread. To do this, we used a Handler thats receives the MainLooper and a Runnable that extends CountDownLatch.

The code of our solution bellow:

```
// SyncHandler.class

public class SyncHandler {
    private SyncRunnable mRunnable;

    public SyncHandler() {
        super();
    }

    public SyncHandler start(@NonNull SyncRunnable runnable) {
        mRunnable = runnable;
        final Looper looper = Looper.getMainLooper();
        Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
        handler.post(mRunnable);

        try {
            mRunnable.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(this, "Error when SyncHandler was awaiting.", e);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public static class ReturnValue<T> {
        public T value;
    }
}

// SyncRunnable.class
public final class SyncRunnable extends CountDownLatch implements Runnable {
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    public static SyncRunnable create(Runnable runnable) {
        return new SyncRunnable(runnable);
    }

   private SyncRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        super(1);
        mRunnable = runnable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(this, "SyncRunnable.run() executed on thread: " + Thread.currentThread());
        mRunnable.run();
        countDown();
    }
}

//And the database call:

// TransactionManager.class
public synchronized void begin(final int ownerHashCode, String ownerName) throws RemoteException {
    SyncHandler handler = new SyncHandler().start(SyncRunnable.create(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mOwner == null) {
                mOwner = ownerHashCode;

                for (Database database : mDatabases) {
                    database.beginTransaction();
                }
            } else if (mOwner == ownerHashCode) {
                throw new DbTransactionException("Error: TransactionOwner == owner");
            }
        }
    }));
}


// DaoHelper.class
public synchronized long insert(Dao dao) {
    final SyncHandler.ReturnValue<Long> value = new SyncHandler.ReturnValue<>();
    SyncHandler handler = new SyncHandler().start(SyncRunnable.create(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(DaoHelper.this, "db.inTransaction: " + mManagerDb.getDatabase().inTransaction());    
            value.value = mManagerDb.getDatabase().insert(mTable, null, mContentValues);
        }
    }));

    return value.value;
}
```

Comment: seems you missed my point, my code was a generic proxy `Binder` that redirected all your `AIDL` calls to some predefined `Thread` / `Looper`, see [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/c28b2021e8b30f4e1ffab0013f8f0780) for a bit enhanced version that uses a small pool of objects to reduce GC activity and uses `wait` / `notify` calls instead of `CountDownLatch`